# Django Forms UpdateView: How to alert user after successful update?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-crispy-forms

I'm using a django UpdateView and cripsy forms to handle my form processing. I'd like to show an alert or popup on the page after the model has successfully updated, i.e. after validation and save.

If I use the `onSubmit` parameter to show an alert, this will just show after the submit button is pressed, but I only want it to show after the valid model has been updated.

Is there an easy way to do this without re-writing a lot of the class methods?

Thank you.

Comment: Please add front end and backend code. Only then i can suggest you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/messages/#module-django.contrib.messages) . Here is an example:

```
# in views.py:

from myapp.forms import ContactForm
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

class ContactView(FormView):
    template_name = 'contact.html'
    form_class = ContactForm
    success_url = '/thanks/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
        # It should return an HttpResponse.
        form.send_email()
        success_message = 'Success! We just sent you an email to confirm'
        messages.success(request, success_message)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Then, in your template (again from [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/messages/#django.contrib.messages.get_messages)):

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
     {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```